# 2D array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to create 2-D array with React Native and when I try to launch this page I receive error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating "rows.map")

Maybe I have mistake when I parse my array, but I don't know what exactly is not correct. Code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { TopSum, BottomSum, TitleLedger } from '../common/text';
import styles from './style


const data = [{
  "date":"Jul 1, 2016",
  "sum": "$2,577.51",
  "source": "Earnings",
  "total": "$0.14"
},{
  "date":"Jul 1, 2016",
  "sum": "$2,577.51",
  "source": "Earnings",
  "total": "$0.14"
}];


export default class Details extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const rows = this.props.data;
    const dataRow = rows.map(row => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.operation}>
                <View style={styles.topSum}>
                  <TopSum label={row.date} />
                  <TopSum label={row.sum} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bottomSum}>
                  <BottomSum label={row.source} />
                  <BottomSum label={row.total} />
                </View>
              </View>
            )
          })
    return (              
         <View title="BALANCE" style={styles.content}>
          {dataRow}
         </View>      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you getting the data from api response or stored locally?

Comment: @MayankShukla locally

Comment: can you show the parent component why from where you are passing the data? because you are using `this.props.data` that means parent should pass `data` in the props.

Comment: @MayankShukla it is const data on the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is you are using `this.props.data` that means `Details` component is expecting the data from parent component in `props` and you are not passing any data in props so `this.props.data` will be **undefined** and it's throwing the error when you are trying to use `map` on it.

Since you defined the data in the same file in the starting so it will be directly available by `data` not by `this.props.data`.

Write it like this:

```
render() {

    const rows = data;      //here

    const dataRow = rows.map(row => {
        ....
    }

    return(
        ....
    )
}
```